# How to use the flex method to make the object in the expected position

Tags: css

I encountered a problem when using CSS typesetting. I want to make the text block on the title side lean against the lower right corner of the item block while retaining the padding spacing of the item, just like the attached photo. I use absolute positioning in the intro block, but it doesn't seem to be a good way, because it will deviate from the position when the device becomes smaller. I want to use the flex method, but I really don't know how to achieve it. I hope it can be done. Thanks for everyone's help.

```css
.wrap {
  height: 547px;
  background: linear-gradient(101.99deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) -3.91%, rgba(45, 82, 61, 0.8) 40.22%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 87.97%), url("../images/park.png");
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.wrap .item {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 67px 50px 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
.wrap .item .demo {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.wrap .item .intro {
  width: 300px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
}
.wrap .item .intro .title {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 57px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}
.wrap .item .intro p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<ul class="wrap">
  <li class="item">
    <span class="demo"></span>
    <div class="intro">
      <h3 class="title">title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos, laudantium.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <span class="demo"></span>
    <div class="intro">
      <h3 class="title">title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos, laudantium.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <span class="demo"></span>
    <div class="intro">
      <h3 class="title">title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos, laudantium.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `margin: auto;` with `display: flex;`:

```css
.wrap {
  height: 547px;
  background: linear-gradient(101.99deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) -3.91%, rgba(45, 82, 61, 0.8) 40.22%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 87.97%), url("../images/park.png");
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.wrap .item {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 67px 50px 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  /* new  */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.wrap .item .demo {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.wrap .item .intro {
  width: 300px;
  color: #fff;
  right: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
  /* new  */
  margin:auto 0 0 auto;
}
.wrap .item .intro .title {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 57px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}
.wrap .item .intro p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<ul class="wrap">
  <li class="item">
    <span class="demo"></span>
    <div class="intro">
      <h3 class="title">title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos, laudantium.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <span class="demo"></span>
    <div class="intro">
      <h3 class="title">title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos, laudantium.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <span class="demo"></span>
    <div class="intro">
      <h3 class="title">title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos, laudantium.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```